# Why it still give an output?

Tags: python

```
map1 = "dust2"
the_best_map = map1
print(map1)
print(the_best_map)

del map1

print(the_best_map)
```

As you see, I assigned two variable, then I deleted one. But `the_best_map` connected to what is map1. That's why I was expecting when I delete `map1`, automatically expected `the_best_map` is deleted. Nevertheless when I run the code, I get that output:

```
dust2
dust2
dust2
```

What is the reason of that. Btw I'm really at the beginning of programming.
Thanks!

Comment: You have a position in memory pointed by one variable. You then create a second variable that points to the same position in memory and you delete the original variable. You will still have the second variable pointing at that position in memory. Take a look at this link https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: You are not deleting the content. You are merely removing a reference. You have two variables referencing the same object

Answer (score 3):

You've deleted `map1`, but `the_best_map` still points to the value `"dust2"`.

If you deleted `the_best_map`, then you'd have a problem trying to print it. See the below simple example.

```
>>> a = 42
>>> b = a
>>> del a
>>> print(b)
42
>>> del b
>>> print(b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1):

You have deleted the map1 variable, but the  the_best_map variable still contains the value of the map1 variable. So, you were able to print the value of the the_best_map variable. If you delete the the_best_map variable then you will get a NameError.